# How use llvm linker?

Tags: c++, llvm

LLVM provides 2 tools llvm-link and llvm-ld. I would like to know:

- how merge all .o file in one ?
- how set a soname like with gcc -Wl,-soname,libsomething.so.1 ?

I would like do this in c++ but if show to me how do that from command line i will found how do to do in c++.

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Link object files or LLVM bitcode files? Create an .so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `llvm-link` is a tool for linking (~ merging) LLVM IR files into another LLVM IR file.
- `llvm-ld` tries to be compatible to `ld`. Note that LLVM currently has no real linking capabilities, so `llvm-ld` calls `gcc` to do the actual final stages.

Note that if you just want to have GCC's functionality, use the clang driver:

```
clang -c file.c -fpic
clang -shared file.o -o file.so
```

You can also pass the `-Wl` flags to `clang` as you'd do for `gcc`:

```
clang -shared file.o -Wl,-soname,libfile.so.8 -o file.so
```

Comment: To add to this, please don't use llvm-ld directly. Heck, please don't ever use any linker directly unless you know exactly what you're doing and you don't have a compiler driver to handle it for you.

Comment: Just a hint, on Mac, use '-dynamiclib' to replace '-shared ....-Wl,-soname,libxxxxx' part

Comment: `LLVM currently has no real linking capabilities`. Is it still the case? (Note http://lld.llvm.org/)